# SQL Database Design - small percentage of rows unique

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have a simple table of products:
Id, ProductCode, Price, Description etc.

And I have 10,000 products... but 100 of them require sound samples (e.g. they are xylophones).
I want to store in the db whether a product has a sound sample.

Therefore, is it better to store in the products table as a "has_sound" boolean (true or false) coloumn, or as a seperate, one column table that just lists all the product id's with sounds?

Storing in the products table means the vast majority will just have "has_sound = false", which seems like a bit of a waste.
But storing just a list of "products with sounds" also seems a bit "wrong" to me.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Yes you are right, both of the way you are thinking are inappropriate because in future you might have condition of checking "has_book" or something then you can't maintain table or field for something specific again and again. Instead I think using field like "product_type" or something similar can be helpful. You can define enums for "product_type".

Answer (score 1):

You have 10,000 rows.

Even if you choose an inefficient 4 byte field size you're looking at all of ~40k on disk by adding a field to the product table. In contrast, an empty innodb table with (int, tinyint) fields is ~100k on disk (plus an additional RAM overhead to hold table metadata). Filling that table with 100 records makes no difference because everything fits within one allocation page.

Neither of these overheads even come *remotely* close to being a performance consideration.

Do what makes the code clearest, simplest and most maintainable for the next developer who comes along (which in this case is to store an extra field on the product table).

Answer (score 0):

The new table is more correctly relational.  If it were me I'd have a two column table, product ID and a BLOB with the sound sample for those products that have a sound sample.  While you could have a Boolean (or NULLable BLOB) on the table, splitting it out allows for better partitioning and additional data around the sound sample (different sample formats, multiple octaves/pitches/notes or whatever) is kept in its correct place next to the sound.

As Levi said though, "the best" is the most maintainable as there will be no significant performance or waste issues at this scale.